# Choose list - multi choose - Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a question, how can I create list like in picture below but with possibility to choose more than 1 element. So I want to have in on cell two names "John, Adam". I finde some ways like: https://gist.github.com/arthurattwell/aa5afc178624bdd6f46c2d0d28d06136, but this will be not celar for other users.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google sheets only supports single selection lists. One way to show a multi select list is with the example you linked, which displays it in a separate popup dialog.

Another, better way is to display the multi-select in a sidebar that always auto-opens from onOpen (as checkboxes since you will have more space) and use setTimeout from the client sidebar maybe every second to show/hide them when the sheet selection is on the right cells.

Comment: Hi @j-doe if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have one question because this App Script you must turn on every time when you open the sheet, is it possible to change this?

Comment: what do you mean by turn on? that script builds the extra menu item during onOpen. But yes the user needs to make many clicks each time. Update: See my "better way" in the answer. its more code but will be a much better user experience and much less clicks.

Comment: I must say i'm new in this, and don't understand "better way"

Comment: Is it possible to add in current cell value if you use that checkbox?
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox
For example if I choose all from checkbox ten in cell I will have "I have a bike, I have a car". Then that think will help my.

Comment: yes its possible, but the question is too broad for stack overflow. use a new question showing specific code and issues for that.

Comment: I created that file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626340/create-in-html-checklist-google-spreadsheet
only problem is, how to insert information to cell.